# Injection of an autowired field failed in a multi-module Maven project - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, maven

I read many posts here at Stackoverflow and at other sites regarding this problem, but didn't find a solution.

I have the following structure of my Maven modules with one main parent pom which declares all these modules (I simplified the structure here in order to show only the relevant part):

[image: Maven modules]

The base and "A" modules depend on the base-api module. The base module contains implementations of the interfaces contained in the base-api module.

I have an interface IFoo in the "base-api" module. The interface IFoo is implemented by a class Foo in the "base" module. The class Foo is annotated with the Spring's "@Service" annotation.

I would like the Foo service to be autowired in my test class which is contained in the module "A":

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    private IFoo foo;
```

I created also a context configuration file for my test which contains among others the following line

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z"/>
```

Both IFoo and Foo are contained in subpackages of x.y.z (in different maven modules, as described above).

When I run the test in Eclipse (with the m2eclipse plugin), then it passes correctly. However, when I run the maven build (mvn clean install), then the following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No matching bean of type [x.y.z.v.IFoo] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To confirm: The implementation class is in base-module? Is this test in base-module or module A?

Comment: The implementation class Foo is in the base module (not in base-api). The test class is in the module A. The test class tests also something else and is therefore not contained directly in the base module. I know that I can mock the Foo service in the test, but I don't want to do it. I would like to use the real imlementation Foo of IFoo in the test.

Comment: Module A doesn't depend on base-module? Then how do you expect it to see the implementation class?

Comment: I don't know, therefore I ask. When I added a dependency on base module in the module A, then it works, but I thought that it's possible to be independent of the real implementation, so that the module A depends only on the base-api module and somehow the implementation from the base module is automatically wired. When I'll have a dependency from the module A to the base module, then I don't need the base-api module, because everything from the base module will be available to the module A. In my opinion it would be better to separate the real implementation using the api module.

Comment: Is it possible to make it work with such dependencies as described in the question and shown in the diagram? I.e. when module A depends only on module base-api, but not on base?

Comment: You need the dependency for Maven to be able to add the implementation class to the classpath. You might be able to scope it so that your module doesn't have a compile-time dependency, but you do have to connect it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `module A` is not dependent on `base module`, any execution on `module A` will not find any of the components in `base module`.  Consequently, any component in `module A` dependent on an implementation from `base module` will fail (since the implementation is not visible from `module A`).

If you simply want components in `base module` to be accessible to `module A` to run tests, you can add a dependency from `base module` to `module A` with `scope` set to `test`.  This way, your tests on `module A` will run just fine.  You will have the flexibility to introduce a completely different JAR at runtime with a different implementation of `IFoo`, if you so require.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I will want the whole to run as a web application? Should I then add an additional web-app module which will have dependencies to all existing modules, i.e. in the case shown in the diagram in my question, to base-api, base and "A" modules?

Comment: Yes, that would be the easiest way to bundle everything in a running application.  We did something like this for a mainframe integration application a long time back.  There was an `interfaces` module which had two implementations - a `mainframe-connector` implementation and a `file-reader` implementation that worked with sample files created from previous mainframe interactions.  The first was used on staging and production while the second on all other environments because they didn't have mainframe connectivity.  We managed this using environment specific Maven profiles.

Comment: Next question: Now the module A has a normal dependency to base-api and a dependency with scope "test" to the base module. The Maven build fails if I try to use a class from the base module in my production code in module A. However, the Workspace Resolution is enabled in the m2eclipse plugin and therefore no error is reported when using a class from the base module in a class in module A. The class can be imported and no error is shown until I perform a Maven build. I don't want to disable the workspace  resolution. Is there a way to show an error in such case after the Eclipse's build?

Comment: I added a new question for the question described in my previous comment:  [Maven dependency with scope “test” & Workspace Resolution enabled in m2eclipse - compile error shown only after the Maven build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769446/maven-dependency-with-scope-test-workspace-resolution-enabled-in-m2eclipse)

Comment: I have added an answer to your new question.