# Maven dependency with scope "test" & Workspace Resolution enabled in m2eclipse - compile error shown only after the Maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

This question is a result of an answer to the following question:
[Injection of an autowired field failed in a multi-module Maven project - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743657/injection-of-an-autowired-field-failed-in-a-multi-module-maven-project-nosuchb)

According to the answer from the aforementioned question, I configured the following structure of my Maven modules:

[image: Maven modules]

In this case, the class Foo from the base module can be used in tests in the module A (e.g. when it's autowired using the IFoo interface), but can't be used in the production code (which is contained in src/main/java).

The Maven build fails when someone adds a reference to the Foo class in a class in the module A in the production code (under src/main/java). However, the automatic build in Eclipse doesn't fail in such case, because I use the m2eclipse plugin which has the Workspace Resolution enabled. I have to run the maven buiild (mvn clean install) to see the compilation failure. Afterwards, the error is still not immediately visible in the affected class in Eclipse. I have to make a change in the affected java class (e.g. add a space and save the file) and then I can see an error in this class. However, what is even more misleading, is the fact, that the compilation error shown in Eclipse has nothing to do with the real copilation error. - The compilation error is shown in the next line after the erroneous line.
 
I don't want to disable the Workspace Resolution in the m2eclipse plugin, so that the newest sources are always used for the Eclipse's compile. However, it would be nice to see such compile error immediately in Eclipse and not have to perform a Maven build in order to see that compile error in Eclipse.

Is it possible to see the compile error immediately after the Eclipse's compile?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are facing a compilation error on Maven build.  Please see a [sample project on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/maven-multi-module) that demonstrates a multi-module Maven set up with the module relationships as shown in your post above.

- `interface` - This module is the base every other module depends upon and is analogous to `base-api` module in your post.  It contains a single interface called `IGreeter`, similar in essence to the `IFoo` interface in your post;
- `implementation` - This module depends on `interface` and contains a single class `Greeter` that implements `IGreeter`.  It is analogous to `base` module in your post.  Note that there is no other code in this module, not even unit tests;
- `service` - This provides a fictional service layer and depends on `interface`.  Additionally, it has a `test` scoped dependency on `implementation`.  It is analogous to `module A` in your post.  It contains a class called `GreetingService` and its associated integration test class `GreetingServiceTest`.  The test can be run from the command line or from Eclipse;
- `web` - This provides a fictional application layer and depends on all the other modules.  It uses `GreetingService` to display a greeting message to the user.  Run it as `mvn clean package tomcat7:run`.

This sample shows how you can write business logic by depending only on certain interfaces (`service` module).  It shows how a specific interface implementation can be chosen during testing to prove that integration works.

This sample also shows how you can choose a specific implementation of an interface at runtime (`web` module).  If you had multiple implementations of `IGreeter` and wanted to use a specific one at runtime, you would add that as a dependency to the `web` module instead of adding the `implementation` module.

Comment: Hi Manish, I analyzed your answer and your sample project on Github. I edited my question a while ago by adding some details to it, because I suppose that you didn't understand what I had previously meant in my question. I forked your repository and made a small change to it in order to show you what I meant in my question: [https://github.com/krzysztof-michalski/maven-multi-module](forked example). I added a reference to the Greeter class from the implementation module in the GreetingService
class in the sample-service module. Just uncomment that line and run maven build to see the error.

Comment: PS. My original project which had been the base for the original question had (simplified) the same structure as your example project at Github.

Comment: Well, if you declare a variable of the implementation in the Service class, you will need the type for that variable to be in scope at compile time.  In that case, you need a compile time dependency from implementation to service.  So, if you wish to have a Greeter instance in your Service class, you need to change the scope of the implementation dependency in the service POM from test to compile.

Comment: I know. It was not my question how to remove the compile error, because I want to see such compile error. Nobody should reference a class from the implementation module in the sample-service module in the production code (src/main/java) of the sample-service module. I'm copying here the last sentence of my main question: "Is it possible to see the compile error immediately after the Eclipse's compile?" I can't copy the whole text of my main question here, therefore please read it if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: The short answer to that would be a no.  We need to remember that Maven works at a project (or module) level not a folder (or sub-folder) level.  With that in mind, you have two conflicting requirements.  You want a component to be accessible to something under src/test but not under src/main within the same module.  None of the Maven dependency scopes allows having this separation.  If you really wanted to achieve this, I would say that you should take your integration tests out of the service module into a new integration-tests module and put the dependency on implementation module there.

Comment: Well, the scope:test allows such separation in the normal Maven build. The problem is that the m2eclipse plugin in Eclipse doesn't handle such case in the same way as the normal Maven build. The compilation in Eclipse doesn't even show the correct compile error, as described in my main question.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.  Maven allows that separation simply because it creates multiple classpaths, one for compilation, another for tests, and so on.  Eclipse as an IDE honours only one classpath per project.

Comment: OK, I had asked, because I hoped, that there is a way to fix it in the m2eclipse plugin, in order to show the same compile error in Eclipse as in the normal Maven build. The problem is that a developer will see the compile error only after performing a Maven build. One usually doesn't perform the Maven builds all the time, but usually e.g. before a commit. Such Maven build is also performed during the automatic build in Hudson at the build server. But the Eclipse's compilation result is what a developer sees always immediately. It's a pity that there is no way to show a correct error there.

Comment: Do you know any workarounds? The idea with the separate project seems to be the only alternative. Is it a best practice to use only mocks instead of the classes from the implementation module in the tests in the sample-service module? If I used only mocks in the sample-service module, then I wouldn't even need a dependency with the scope:test to the implementation module. On the other hand, I like the functionality of the scope:test provided by Maven, because I can decide on my own in each test in the sample-service module, whether I want to use mocks or real implementations.